# CSS HTML center text in circle

Tags: html, css, border, centering

I have a circle and in it I have a number, my question is: how do I put the number in center of circle?

**I know there are other articles similar to this but they did not help me.**

Here is what I have tried:

```
.circle{

    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #0276FD; 
    border: 12px solid #0276FD;
    color: black;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;   
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Result]

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) could be of help for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+center+text+in+circle+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Thank you, I will do so next time! @mplungjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) for this

```css
.circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #0276FD; 
    border: 12px solid #0276FD;
    color: black;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;   
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">1</div>
```